# Why does my Epson R3000 printer turn itself off?

Tags: printer

After a period, my new printer turns itself off. The green light turns off, the display turns off and it doesn't receive print tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally assumed this was some sort of error, but turns out it was configured out of the box to act this way.

In the menus on the printer itself, go to Setup > Printer Setup > Power Off Timer and change it from the default "4 hours" to "Off".

Comment: You can accept your own answer, which will prevent this question from getting bumped up now and then. (This will happen occasionally to posts without an accepted answer).